# Package.Open() exception: Access to path is denied

Tags: c#

I been trying to fix this problem for the whole day, but no matter what I do I keep on getting the same exception: UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled  at line
 using (Package package = Package.Open(d.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))

The full code is:

```
NTAccount act = new NTAccount("c9lu-PC","c9lu");

DirectoryInfo d = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

DirectorySecurity security = d.GetAccessControl();

security.AddAccessRule(new    FileSystemAccessRule(act,FileSystemRights.FullControl,InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));

d.SetAccessControl(security);

using (Package package = Package.Open(d.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))     // where the exception occurs
{

    PackageHelper.createPart(package, "/pages.zip" , MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip,
                    (stream) =>
                    {
                        using (var parts = ZipPackage.Open(stream, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    );
}
```

I really don't know what the problem is, please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it have something to do with the fact that you're passing in a directory into the first parameter of Package.Open instead of a file name? Should be more like this:

```
// This gives you a directory object. It's all a directory/folder. No File.
DirectoryInfo d = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

// So use the Combine method to create a full path to a file
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(d.FullName, "pages.zip");

...
// Then use that full path to create the Package.
Package.Open(fileName, ...
```

Comment: Hi Tim

I am actually passing the directory's full name. What I am trying to do is to create the package inside that directory, so how would I specify the package's path?

Comment: Right, you're passing the directory's full name, but not the file name. You need to give it a file name (directory and file name). I think you've moved that part into the createPart call for some reason.

Comment: If I only use d.Name instead of d.FullName,which the exception does disappear, but there is no package created inside the folder after I run the program.

Comment: d.Name is still just a directory. You need to do a file name. I'll update my answer with a code example.

Comment: thank you so much Tim! It worked! This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, and I am really starting to like it. :)

Comment: Good, glad I was able to help out and give you a good impression of StackOverflow - Welcome! Now just remember to give points and/or mark things as answers so that people continue to help you out. :)